# Localizar atribuição de chamado glpi 10.4

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, mariadb

Estou fazendo uma consulta onde ira trazer os tickets atribuídos a cada técnico mas não encontro a coluna de ID dos técnicos atribuído as únicas colunas que contem o id do usuário e users_id_lastupdater,users_id_recipient tabela glpi_ticket, precisava saber qual e a coluna/tabela onde encontra as atribuições dos tickets.

Comment: Você fez essa mesma pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/590427/5878

Comment: Considerando que o post é duplicado, os comentários foram desativados aqui para evitar descentralização de informações, mas podem ser usados no post original. Queira restaurar aquela postagem e proceder conforme orientações dadas lá, se for uma dúvida de desenvolvimento de software.